# What is a Silo in a software engineering context?

Tags: terminology

I'm an intern software developer and in my career I've occasionally heard the term 'silo' being used. I've looked into it myself and tried to nail down exactly what it means, but I seem to be getting mixed results. By my understanding, in a general context it means keeping *something* separated and abstracted away from *something* or *someone else*, usually due to access or *understanding* constraints (not sure if understanding is really the right word to use here.) I've encountered it in two more specific cases:

- **Software:** in which a developer or team of developers has complete control over the functionality of a piece of code which no one else can (or will) interact with beyond its I/O interface. I've also heard it used to describe a situation where one person or team works on the frontend of an application and the another works on the backend, completely separating the functionality.
- **Data or Information:** this one I'm not as sure of. From what I can tell it refers to data itself being completely disconnected from any application architecture. This confuses me a little because I can't really think of a situation where you *wouldn't* do this, but as stated I am only an intern and could be a little naive to some software development practices.

So are both of those right? Can the term 'silo' be used to describe both software and data? How would you describe a 'silo', and in what context would you use the term?

Comment: It's generally a "knowledge silo" in my experience, and isn't specific to software engineering.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Are you saying that if you saw the term in a software engineering context, it would mean neither of the specific cases I have been able to identify? And while I realise that the term is not specific to SE, I am specifically asking about it in a SE context - while the term may have different connotations and implications in other fields, what would usually be the intended implication of the term when referring to software engineering?

Comment: Sorry, but the term Silo has AFAIK no widely accepted, specific meaning in software engineering. So better ask those people who use this term what they mean, not us. On this site, this just leads to "guessing games", which are not welcomed by the community here.

Comment: I have seen this used, too, but don't remember the context. It would help if you could use it in a sentence. I've never heard it used at work so I think it might be one of those online made up terms you only find on reddit and other amateur forums.

Comment: @Rob Actually, I've just found it used in the Stack Overflow Enterprise homepage (scroll down a couple of page heights) in which it seems to be being used in the 'knowledge' context that jonrsharpe mentioned. But I don't know what that *means* in this specific context? https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise

Comment: There, and everywhere else I've encountered it, _silo_ is an organisational term. It refers to knowledge, responsibility, control or whatever being restricted to a particular group or unit in an organisation. It'll only be reflected in software the same way any other organisational structure is reflected in software.

Comment: @JackParkinson: Useless is right, the term "Silo" (besides its [original meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silo)) is sometimes used to compare a small organisational group inside a bigger one with a "house without windows", which means they do not share their knowledge with others. This is in no way specific to software engineering, as I already wrote - there is no *specific* meaning in software engineering, at least not in a widely accepted manner.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Information Silo?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_silo)  As others have pointed out, it's just a generic term applied in a specific context.

Comment: You put rockets it it to look dangerous and your competition doesn't make aggressive business moves. No seriously i have never heard of it. Your best bet is to ask the people you heard it from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

silo: a tall tower or pit on a farm used to store grain.

The vertical orientation is key. It means you have a stack of sub-systems/components that are interdependent, that communicate with each other, that deliver to each other or have some other up-down relationship with one another. That is one silo.

Using the term implies there are multiple silos, each of which is independent of any of the other silos, from a technical or organisational perspective.

So you use the term to denote isolation between several complex systems.